# Wien Bridge Oscillator in Multsim Values

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, multisim, wien-bridge

I am trying to build a Wien Bridge Oscillator in Multisim that has a frequency of 3.6 kHz. However my graph is very distorted and I'm guessing its because of the op amp component values. Does anyone have any recommendations to fix this?

[image: op amp configuration values]
[image: transient analysis results]

Comment: Search me for an answer to the same problem on one bridge using diode pair feedback

Comment: No SIRI I said Wein  not one bridge

Comment: Looks quite similar to [this other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/370121/unexpected-waveform-for-wien-bridge-oscillator-with-limiter-circuit)

Comment: Duplicate of this perhaps https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/370135/how-to-dc-bias-the-output-of-a-wien-bridge-oscillator-so-that-it-oscillates-abou